# How can I navigate between screens in a React Native Expo project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I navigate between my home screen and another screen in a React Native Expo project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different type of navigations to navigate between screens

Take a look on the documentation about [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)